# SAP Cloud Platform Deployment - invalid contents (?) in neo-app.json

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I have a test-app in SAP cloud platform. While trying to deploy it in the cloud (and after a few successful deployments) I suddenly get the message below:

[image]

File looks perfectly alright (definition below, validated also via JSONLint), app is working and makes use of the defined destinations in Web IDE. If I copy it to another application using similar destinations and try to deploy it, deployment screen appears as expected. If I take the original file from the other application and use it to replace the file "having the issue" I still get the same message. Being suspicious of some browser cache issue, I switched browsers and retried - again the same result. Of course is quite possible that I miss something (that's why I'm here) but looks like a Web IDE bug to me. Does it ring any bells?

```
{
  "welcomeFile": "/webapp/index.html",
  "routes": [
   {
      "path": "/resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/resources",
        "version": "1.60.18"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/test-resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/test-resources",
        "version": "1.60.18"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Test Resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/DEV",
      "target": {
        "type": "destination",
        "name": "DEV"
      },
      "description": "Development Env DEV"
    },
    {
      "path": "/DevOps",
      "target": {
        "type": "destination",
        "name": "DevOps"
      },
      "description": "Dev Ops"
    }    
  ],
  "sendWelcomeFileRedirect": true    
}
```

Comment: Unrelated. How is the ms graph experiment going, is it doable?

Comment: Aaah, the msgraph experiment went fine, confused initially seeing only some of my e-mails but found the filter in the code and inbox is coming full in SAPUI5, thank you :D 
This one is about trying to update (PATCH) a work item in Azure (initial reason who led me to the msgraph sample), managed to read it and fetch my data but I get all kind of response codes except success (and an update) on update, neo-app.json went crazy during one of these consecutive deployments (easier than changing every time the manifest in Azure to correspond to the different addresses assigned by Web IDE on testing)